# How to combine two lists?

Tags: ansible

I have a task which uses `with_subelements` but it's terrible slow for big list (especially that most of the elements has duplicates and I don't need to run it multiple times for them).

So I'm looking for a way to optimize it somehow. I wish to get all unique elements from that list - let say `settings` in the example below:

inventory:

```
my_list:
  - { name: foo, settings: ['x', 'y', 'z'] }      
  - { name: bar, settings: ['x', 'y', 'q', 'w'] }
```

tasks:

```
- name: get all settings
  set_fact:
    all_settings="{{ my_list|map(attribute='settings')|list }}"

- name: show results
  debug:
    var=all_settings
```

results:

```
"var": {
        "all_settings": [
            [
                "x",
                "y",
                "z"
            ],
            [
                "x",
                "y",
                "q"
                "w"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

**I stuck at this point. How can I combine those list together ?**

I'm looking for a way to get `['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w']`

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a [`union`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters).

Off the top of my head:

```
all_settings="{{ foo|map(attribute='settings')|union(bar|map(attribute='settings')) }}"
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't loop on `my_list` elements manually. It's just an example with two elements for simplicity but normally I have much more.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you're _really_ trying to do.

Comment: I think it's quite clear from the post. `flatten` does the trick since it will combine a list of lists of any size into a single list as opposed to `union` which combines just two lists.

Answer (score 2):

What about this ?

```
- name: get all settings
  set_fact:
    all_settings="{{ my_list|map(attribute='settings')|list|flatten|unique }}"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should work:

```
...
all_settings="{{ my_list|map(attribute='settings')|list | sum(start=[]) | unique }}"
```